# BEGIN BREAKPAD MICRODUMP crash when calling method in onKeyDown

Tags: android

I have a very strange issue with an app I am working on. When the app is launched it calls `Activity A`, from there it calls `Activity B`. In `Activity B` I override the onKeyDown method which calls a function as follows:

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
    {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
        {
            disconnectDatabase();
        }
        else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL)
        {
            QueryEditor queryEditor = (QueryEditor) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_queryEditor);
            queryEditor.formatQueryText();
        }

        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

The `disconnectDatabase` function is as follows:

```
private void disconnectDatabase()
{
    UserInterfaceManager uiManager = new UserInterfaceManager(ConnectedDBManagerHost.this);
    if (uiManager.showYesNoDialog(getString(R.string.are_you_sure_you_want_to_disconnect_the_current_database), getString(R.string.are_you_sure), false))
    {
        ConnectionsManager.connectedDatabase = null;
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        finish();
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

The `showYesNoDialog` method builds an AlertDialog and returns the result of what user presses. This loads correctly and I press the Yes but then it crashes, but the crash doesn't come from my app, but instead seems to come from the hardware of the tablet, by looks of it the graphics driver.

The error that is shown in the logcat is as follows:

```
8-06 22:41:47.122 28777-28777/com.BoardiesITSolutions.MysqlManager E/tegra_memtrack_hal: Error: Could not find any nvmap heaps.
08-06 22:41:47.123 28777-28777/com.BoardiesITSolutions.MysqlManager E/tegra_memtrack_hal: Error: Could not find any nvmap heaps.
08-06 22:41:47.123 28777-28777/com.BoardiesITSolutions.MysqlManager E/tegra_memtrack_hal: Error: Could not find any nvmap heaps.
08-06 22:41:48.582 28777-28777/com.BoardiesITSolutions.MysqlManager E/Ads: JS: Uncaught ReferenceError: AFMA_ReceiveMessage is not defined (:1)
08-06 22:41:53.891 29187-28777/? A/google-breakpad: -----BEGIN BREAKPAD MICRODUMP-----
08-06 22:41:53.891 29187-28777/? A/google-breakpad: V WebView:51.0.2704.81
08-06 22:41:53.893 29187-28777/? A/google-breakpad: O A arm64 02 aarch64 google/volantis/flounder:6.0.1/MOB30P/2960889:user/release-keys
08-06 22:41:53.893 29187-28777/? A/google-breakpad: G OpenGL ES 3.1 NVIDIA 343.00|NVIDIA Corporation|NVIDIA Tegra
08-06 22:41:53.893 29187-28777/? A/google-breakpad: S 0 0000007FC76151A0 0000007FC7615000 0000000000002000
08-06 22:41:53.896 29187-28777/? A/google-breakpad: S 0000007FC7615000 101ABAC7550000004B5161C77F0000004C5161C77F0000000000430001000000008911C755000000B668
```

FYI I haven't included the whole logcat, it looks to be mostly just a memory dump.

As this crash isn't coming from within my app I have absolutely no idea where to look or what would cause this. Instead of calling a new activity, I have tried just calling finish but doesn't make any difference. It doesn't do it all the time either, it does do it most of the time, but occasionally it will work perfectly fine.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to this issue ?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I think its something specific to a particular device